# Format JsonResponse data into a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, python-3.x

I am trying to format Django JsonResponse data into a table in my template. Here is my code so far.

**script**

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    (function($){
        function processForm( e ){
            var inputText = $('#input-Text').val();
            var inputTemplate = $('#input-Template').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/parse/',    //replace this with url that you want to hit without reloading the page
                dataType: 'text',
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
                    var result = JSON.parse(data);
                    alert(data);
                    $.each(result, function (i, val) {
                        console.log(val);
                    });
                },
                error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                     // This is executed when some error occures
                     alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });

            e.preventDefault();
        }
        $('#my-form').submit( processForm );
    })(jQuery);</script>
```

**views.py**

```
return JsonResponse({'result': result})
```

It alerts me, on success,

> {'result' : [['Keys'], ['148']]}

I am trying to generate a table with first item in the result as table header and others are like table rows. I have little understanding with Jquery/ajax/js. Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: table headers should be dynamic in my case. I get **data.length** as **44**. But I am expecting it to be **2**.

Comment: That is not consistent with your example. We cannot guess what you have on your server